# D3 CSV Import Sort Function Display

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am going for this: http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_10/14_div_tooltip.html except with custom data that has two fields: a "Month" and a "Ratio."

This my javascript code, which looks very similar to that on the link posted above. http://pastebin.com/KG2tX5Xm
The main differences would be in the scale (mine goes across months) and the x, y attributes which would need to be based off data.Ratio or data.Month.

When I view the source of my page, I see that the rectangles' coordinates do change after clicking; however, they are staying in position. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that changes when you `.sort()` the selection (of `rect` elements in this case) is the index of each element. The data does not change. The example you've linked to uses the index of the respective element to determine the x position of the bars after sorting and during redrawing. Hence, the positions of the bars change.

In your code, you're not using the index of the bars to determine their position at all. You're using the data bound to the elements, which does not change when sorting.

Your general approach is different from the one taken in the example you've linked to. There, the data itself is sorted (or rather the selection) and its order matters for the positions of the bars. In what you're doing, the order of the data does not matter because you're only using the data itself.

So to make the sorting have any effect, change your code to use the index to determine the position of the bars:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(function(a, b) {
            if (sortOrder) {
                    return d3.ascending(a.Ratio, b.Ratio);
            } else {
                    return d3.descending(a.Ratio, b.Ratio);
            }
    })
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
            return i * 50;
    })
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * x.rangeBand();
    });
```

Comment: That works. Why does the padding disappear after the sort though?

Comment: I'm just using the range band to determine the position there. You can tweak that as appropriate in your case.